# How to modifiy this String template?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Following is the String Template :

```
     XYZ PROCESSING SERVICES GMBH                                          
     HAHNSTR. 25                                                            
     60528 CITY                                                        

     BEGLEITZETTEL ZU CORT UMSATZBAND - GUTSCHRIFT                          

                SAMMEL UEBERWEISUNGSAUFTRAG                                 

          CASSETTENNUMMER :                                                 

         ERSTELLUNGSDATUM :  $FileCreationDate$                                       
            ZEICHENDICHTE :  38K                                            
            HEADER-ANZAHL :         1                                       
            ANZAHL SATZ C :                       $ANZAHLSATZC$                         
         EUR SUMME SATZ C :                    $EURSUMMESATZC$                      
      KONTROLSUMME KTONR. :           $KONTROLSUMMEKTONR$                        
      KONTROLSUMME BLZ    :            $KONTROLSUMMEBLZ$                         
         EMPFÄNGER NAME   :  L CONSORS S.A.                                 
         EMPFÄNGER BLZ    :  12345678                                      
         EMPFÄNGER KTONR. :  0987654321                                     
                      ORT :  CITY                                      
                    DATUM :  $Datum$
```

But when you run the Java Program with this Template, you get the following output, i.e. the position of first line is moved automatically, but the required output is the same as mentioned above :

```
 XYZ PROCESSING SERVICES GMBH                                          
     HAHNSTR. 25                                                            
     60528 CITY                                                        

     BEGLEITZETTEL ZU CORT UMSATZBAND - GUTSCHRIFT                          

                SAMMEL UEBERWEISUNGSAUFTRAG                                 

          CASSETTENNUMMER :                                                 

         ERSTELLUNGSDATUM :  $FileCreationDate$                                       
            ZEICHENDICHTE :  38K                                            
            HEADER-ANZAHL :         1                                       
            ANZAHL SATZ C :                       $ANZAHLSATZC$                         
         EUR SUMME SATZ C :                    $EURSUMMESATZC$                      
      KONTROLSUMME KTONR. :           $KONTROLSUMMEKTONR$                        
      KONTROLSUMME BLZ    :            $KONTROLSUMMEBLZ$                         
         EMPFÄNGER NAME   :  L CONSORS S.A.                                 
         EMPFÄNGER BLZ    :  12345678                                      
         EMPFÄNGER KTONR. :  0987654321                                     
                      ORT :  CITY
```

The java Code for this is :

```
StringTemplateGroup templateGroup = new StringTemplateGroup(
                "spam group", "src/main/resources");
        StringTemplate logDTABegleitzettel = templateGroup
                .getInstanceOf("Template");
        logDTABegleitzettel.setAttribute("FileCreationDate", fileCreationDate);
        logDTABegleitzettel.setAttribute("ANZAHLSATZC", numberofCRecords);
        logDTABegleitzettel.setAttribute("EURSUMMESATZC", sumofTranxAmounts);
        logDTABegleitzettel.setAttribute("KONTROLSUMMEKTONR",
                sumofAccountNumbers);
        logDTABegleitzettel.setAttribute("KONTROLSUMMEBLZ", sumofBankSortCodes);
        logDTABegleitzettel.setAttribute("Datum", dateOfFile);
```

Comment: show us your code. Are you trimming the String by any chance?